# No qualifying bean of type [] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I get an org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

expected single matching bean but found 2: C, D

My class structure looks something like this:

```
interface A{
}


abstract class B{
}

@Component
class C extends B implements A{
}

@Component
class D extends B implements A{
}
```

Class C and D are driver classes that lie in different modules. 
The module in which Class D lies has a dependency on the module that has class C.
class B and interface A lie in a lower level module. 
Implementations of C and D look very similar in method signatures and other member variables, if that makes any difference. Please Help!! Thanks!!

Comment: you must be autowiring of type B or A. In that case you need to mention the qualifier attribute. Or change the autowiring type to C or D. Using @Qualifier annotation would be best way to differentiate

Comment: @premkumar I don't have autowiring for any of these.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is some StackTrace for that `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`. So, that will show you place where you try to obtain non-unique bean from the `BeanFactory`

Comment: may be auto-wired by setters or through constructors somewhere in your code?